# What is "Tooltime" jars in JAX-WS documentation?

Tags: jax-ws

I haven't read the whole documentation but I find it hard to find that term in a self explaining context. What does "Tooltime Jars" on [that page](http://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.7/docs/ch02.html#jar-dependency) mean ?

If you feel like down voting this, please at least mention why.

Comment: Mr secret down-voter, trust me, english isn't my language and I really didn't know what the heck does `Tooltime jars` mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "tooltime" they are refering to the jars needed by tools (as opposed to runtime). xjc and the like.

Comment: Thank you ! So you mean these are jars used by 3rd party tools ? If yes, then why do they care to list them ? 3rd party tools should take care of that themselves. Or did I get it wrong ? One side question, is it really obvious ? That I deserve a down vote for it ?

Comment: Its not 3rd party tools. The dependencies are for the metro/jax-ws tooling. You need them to build stuff but not at runtime.